# Why are there unexpected spaces on my PDF using FPDF with PHP?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, cell, fpdf

I'm using FPDF to write some text on a PDF. I'm displaying 8 different cells of text. The Cells are being displayed, but after two cells, it puts the next cell onto a new page as If I had asked for a new PDF page to be made, but I did not. I'm guessing it is somehow pushing them down and pushing it onto the next page. How can I get rid of these annoying spaces and make it all fit on only the one PDF page?

I am using the FPDF Class - http://fpdf.org/en/doc/index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at

> SetAutoPageBreak(boolean auto [, float
>   margin])
>
> Description Enables or disables the
>   automatic page breaking mode. When
>   enabling, the second parameter is the
>   distance from the bottom of the page
>   that defines the triggering limit. By
>   default, the mode is on and the margin
>   is 2 cm.